# How can I insert text every n characters that isn't between two specific pieces of text?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have html that I'm getting ready to insert into the dom. Before I do that, I need to insert the tag  every 30 characters. This is very easy doing something like so:

```
var html = html.replace(/(.{30})/g, '$1<wbr>');
```

However, this simple solution often times will insert the  tag into an existing html tag. For example, this could end up happening:

```
<spa<wbr>n> Some text here </span>
```

The html may be many children deep like so:

```
<div>
    This is some text that we need to treat. <br />
    <span> Here is some more text. <a href="#"> Click here. </a> </span>
</div>
```

What's the best way to approach this? Is regex a possible solution? Or do I need to write a javascript function? I was hoping I could figure out how to write a regular expression similar to the one above that inserts text every n characters UNLESS it's between the characters '<' and '>'.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't `replace` in HTML string. Just recurse over all text nodes of your DOM tree, and split them up.

Comment: What's the problem you're facing? Shouldn't there be a CSS solution?

Comment: @Bergi , I'm in the process of writing a recursive method, but I was really hoping to get this done in a line or two.

Comment: word-wrap: break-word , would be nice but CSS is out of the question unfortunately

Comment: @Tyler, who in the world is browsing in Links?

Comment: @tenub I don't follow.

Comment: @Tyler, Sorry, I meant *Lynx*. ;) In case you're still confused, it's the only explanation I can think of as to why you wouldn't simply use CSS.

Comment: Ahh. :) This is for a chrome extension, which modifies an existing website. The layout of the site is very complex, and some elements are updated and resized using javascript. Some aren't. It may seem a little bonkers, but just throwing in the <wbr> tags is so much easier than modifying the layout of the site....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution. Normally I wouldn't want to use jquery but time is of the essence.

```
var el = $('<div>' + html + '</div>');
var allChildren = el.find('*');

allChildren.each(function() {
    for(var i = 0, len = this.childNodes.length; i < len; i++) {
        if(this.childNodes[i].nodeType === 3) {
            var newHtml = this.childNodes[i].nodeValue.replace(/(.{30})/g, '$1<wbr>');
            $(this.childNodes[i]).replaceWith(newHtml);
        }
    }
});

html = el.html();
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use this:

```
(.{30}.*?\s)
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/nL0qT2

Javascript:

```
var html = html.replace(/(.{30}.*?\s)/g, '$1<br />');
```

So this will insert the `<br>` tag on the next following space after the 30th character, so the `<br>` doesn't get inserted inside any word or tag.

Comment: Unless, you know, there's inner html. Then it isn't every 30 characters.